# Node JS: Как различить обычную ссылку от ссылки с картинкой

Tags: javascript, node.js

На вход подаются ссылки. Например:

`https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/774706529609580586.png?v=1`
`https://www.youtube.com/`

При переходе на первую у меня будет изображение. При переходе на вторую - сайт.
Как мне их различать с точки зрения кода? Мне нужно отсеять все ссылки, которые не являются картинками и способ посмотреть на окончание не подходит, тк в конце первой ссылки есть `?v=1`, но при этом это картинка.

Comment: Никак. Ссылка это просто строка. Что в ответ на неё отдаст сервер знает только он. Вплоть до того, что в разное время или разным людям сожет отдавать разное.

Comment: @AlexeyTen да ладно тебе. сгонять по адресу HEAD запросом и разобрать content-type (as mime-type) из заголовков

Comment: Про «сгонять» в вопросе не было. И это не помогает от разных ответов в зависимости от запроса 

Comment: Каких-либо ограничений по решению я в вопросе тоже не вижу. Рассказывайте, что, да как и куда нужно сгонять и что за content-type.

Comment: Под "сгонять по адресу HEAD" понимается запросить не ресурс(GET|POST), а только заголовки(HEAD) и получить тип контента - `Content-Type: image/png`. Но если точно известно, что окончания "правильные" достаточно разобрать адрес `(new URL('abc?123')).pathname === 'abc'`, т.к. в примере не окончание, а параметры запроса.

Comment: Воспользовался либой node-fetch. С помощью неё посмотрел content-type в заголовках. Результатом доволен. Спасибо всем за помощь.

Comment: @AlexeyTen я решил таки написать ответ :) запрашивается примерно 4кб с адреса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы тщательно проверить является ли картинкой то, что отдаётся по url, нужно запросить небольшой кусочек данных из начала ответа и проанализировать эти байты библиотекой [file-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type). Если в коллекции сигнатур `file-type` есть такие данные то вызов вернёт `MIME type`, если такой сигнатуры нет - будем диагностировать по заголовку `content-type`.

Функция `getMimeTypeByURL` возвращает `MIME type` ресурса.

Вспомогательная функция `checkImageByURL` возвращает `true`, если ресурс - картинка. `checkImageByURL` вернёт `null` если при запросе произошла ошибка. `checkImageByURL` вернёт `true` если ресурс имеет тип `image/svg+xml`, так что сделайте более кастомную проверку, если она вам нужна.

```
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const { URL } = require('url');
const FileType = require('file-type');

(async () => {
  const urls = [
    'https://random.dog/53d44c97-25bc-4503-9bed-5e9d6bb0e53a.mp4',
    'https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/774706529609580586.png?v=1',
    'https://www.youtube.com/',
    'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/img/sprites.svg',
    'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/0/'
  ];
  for (const url of urls) {
    await checkImageByURL(url);
  }
})();

/**
 * @param {string} url
 * @returns {Promise<boolean | null>}
 */
async function checkImageByURL(url) {
  /** @type {boolean | null} */
  let isImage = null;
  try {
    const mimeType = await getMimeTypeByURL(url);

    isImage = mimeType?.startsWith('image');

    console.log(`url=${url}, mimeType=${mimeType}, isImage=${isImage}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    console.warn(`url=${url}, mimeType=NULL, isImage=${isImage}`);
  }
  return isImage;
}

/**
 * @param {string} incomingUrl
 * @returns {Promise<string | undefined>}
 */
async function getMimeTypeByURL(incomingUrl) {
  const url = new URL(incomingUrl);

  if (!['http:', 'https:'].includes(url.protocol)) {
    throw new Error(`PROTOCOL "${url.protocol}" is not supported...`);
  }

  /** @type {http.IncomingMessage} */
  const responseStream = await new Promise(
    (resolve) => (url.protocol === 'https:' ? https : http).get(url, resolve)
  );
  if (responseStream.statusCode !== 200) {
    console.error(`loading fail: ${url}, statusCode=${responseStream.statusCode}`);
    throw new Error(`UNHANDLED RESPONSE STATUS ${responseStream.statusCode}`);
  }

  const responseFileType = await FileType.fromStream(responseStream);
  responseStream.destroy();
  const responseContentType = responseStream.headers['content-type']?.replace(/;\s*charset=.+$/, '');

  return responseFileType
    ? responseFileType.mime
    : responseContentType;
}
```

Результат в консоли:

```bsh
url=https://random.dog/53d44c97-25bc-4503-9bed-5e9d6bb0e53a.mp4,
  mimeType=video/mp4, isImage=false

url=https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/774706529609580586.png?v=1,
  mimeType=image/png, isImage=true

url=https://www.youtube.com/,
  mimeType=text/html, isImage=false

url=https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/img/sprites.svg,
  mimeType=image/svg+xml, isImage=true

loading fail: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/0/, statusCode=404
Error: UNHANDLED RESPONSE STATUS 404
    at getMimeTypeByURL (/Users/nörbörnën/git/stackoverflow-practice/src/file-type-1/index.js:55:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async checkImageByURL (/Users/nörbörnën/git/stackoverflow-practice/src/file-type-1/index.js:28:22)
    at async /Users/nörbörnën/git/stackoverflow-practice/src/file-type-1/index.js:16:5
url=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/0/,
  mimeType=NULL, isImage=null
```