# Как найти и получить ссылку в строке node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Хочу сделать парсер ссылок для бота, но меня интересует сам процесс определения в строке ссылки

Я нашел то что меня интересует, но ссылки бывают разные, а с регулярками у меня очень и очень плохо.

вот что я нашел

```
string.match("((http|https):\/\/)?(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}");
```

Но она не принимает параметры и если ссылка выйдет типа https://test.test2.ru, то в ответ я получу только https://test.test2, если я дополню регулярку, мне не совсем понятно как получить параметры, есть ли способ как сделать универсальный парсер ссылок из строки

```
В данной строке присутствует ссылкаhttps://test.test2.ru/parametr1 и ссылка https://test2.ru (пробел отсутствует специально)
```

Я находил много примеров, но не один не удовлетворяет задачи

**Дополнение:**

```
checkURL(string) {
    try {
        const stringIsURL = string.match("((http|https):\/\/)?(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}");
        new URL(stringIsURL);
        return true;
    } catch {
        return false;
    }
```

Далее я использую из класса метод

```
        if (Link.checkURL(message.content)) {
        message.channel.send('В сообщении присутствует ссылка');
    }
```

Вроде бы все работает, но...
Вот по сути то что мне нужно [Node JS: Как различить обычную ссылку от ссылки с картинкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1301373/473526), но там уже заранее подготовленные ссылки, а мне нужно получать их из сообщений пользователей, то есть определить в сообщении ссылку

Comment: *"то в ответ я получу только https://test.test2"*  --- про какой ответ идёт речь?  string.match даст массив с данными. Причём по нулевому индексу вполне будет совпадение полное

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я проверяю ссылки через URL объект, сейчас дополню вопрос

Comment: `<a href="https://">` бывает?

Comment: @nörbörnën, речь идет не о элементах из верстки, а о методе получения полной ссылки из вводной строки, например сообщения пользователя

Comment: ну, решите задачу в лоб `'В данной строке присутствует ссылкаhttps://test.test2.ru/parametr1 и ссылка https://test2.ru (пробел отсутствует специально)'.split(/\s+/).filter((x) => /https?:\/\//.test(x)).map((x) => x.replace(/^.+?(?=http)/, ''))`